# jquery/Raphaël stop and start

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

i got a lot of code and wanted to add a stop and start button to my animation. So when the user presses start it will start everything and when he presses stop it stops. However iam suing more than one library. J query and Raphael. Is it possible to do this? or not? Thanks

Comment: Can you boil this down to a basic example on jsfiddle?

Comment: stackoverflow is not a research assistant. please perform a search in your favored search engine, you'll encounter plenty information on this. you may want to read the [FAQ entry on what kinds of questions best fits here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Comment: I did this using jQuery and Raphael at http://jolora.co.uk - it's used for the circular timer on the home page slideshow. Dig in and you'll find what you need. The only difference is I start and stop the animation on hover.